# SSRS Bulleted list

Tags: reporting-services

When I am using the Bulleted ListStyle in SSRS, how do I make sure the text on the second line onwards to align with the text on the first line?

e.g. (*) as the bullet point

```
*    Today is a
     good day.

instead of having

*    Today is a
  good day.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By setting HangingIndent to 0 or nothing, it will do the job